# Windows 7 network adapter fails to start

Tags: windows-7, home-networking, network-adapter

I need to restart my Windows 7 computer at least 3-4 times to get my local area connection active. I have tried every option related to power but it hasn't helped. I have the drivers installed, but it shows the error "network adapters drivers not found". When I restart it 3-4 times, then it automatically starts.

What is going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you run chkdsk yet? have you tried uninstalling the device and letting it reinstall?  have you tried the computer vendors website or the video cards website for new drivers?  Do you run windows updates automatically?  Have you run windows update manually?

Comment: ya I have updated my drivers online and my windows updates itself automatically and I have also re installed it. but no progress is shown.